# Tree of select in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for how can I do a tree of selects in JavaScript, but i can use any library (actually I use JQuery).

I don't need show the tree. I need show one select in HTML (programatically) and depends of the user clicked, i will show another select witch differents options depending on the value of the first select.

I need save the user clicked value at every step, too.

I've a tree with heights of depth, therefore i need 8 selects which depend on the value of the previous select.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Any chance we can see this `tree` with `heights` and `depths`? Also your attempt(s)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for specific programming problems. You have to show what you tried and what is the problem that you are encountering to get helped.

Comment: You are looking for *cascading dropdowns*.

Answer (score 0):

Take this fiddle as your example

http://jsfiddle.net/mer4ovzb/

**HTML** will be like this

```
<select id ="category">

<option class="category">Fruit</option>
<option class="category">Veg</option>
<option class="category">Nuts</option>
<option class="category">Drinks</option>

</select>

<select id="subcategory">

<option class="fruit veg nuts drink">Product 1</option>
<option class="drink">Product 2</option>
<option class="veg nuts drink">Product 3</option>
<option class="veg nuts">Product 4</option>

</select>
```

**CSS**

```
.fruit, .veg, .nuts, .drink {
    display:none;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#category").change(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "Fruit") {
        $(".veg").hide();
        $(".nuts").hide();
        $(".drink").hide();
        $(".fruit").show();
      } else if($(this).val() == "Veg") {
        $(".fruit").hide();
        $(".nuts").hide();
        $(".drink").hide();
        $(".veg").show();
      } else if($(this).val() == "Nuts") {
        $(".fruit").hide();
        $(".veg").hide();
        $(".drink").hide();
        $(".nuts").show();
      } else if($(this).val() == "Drinks") {
        $(".fruit").hide();
        $(".nuts").hide();
        $(".veg").hide();
        $(".drink").show();
      }
   });

});
```

Let me know if it is helpful